# Can't insert row into Cockroachdb table using pg

Tags: node.js, postgresql, aws-lambda, node-postgres, cockroachdb

I have an AWS Lamda function that gets some computed data and then is supposed to insert it into a table in Cockroach. I can *create* the table, but I cannot add rows into it.

Here is the pg part of my code: (I'll end up using pooling, but the connection is for testing and should do the trick):

It's also worth noting that my query looks exactly like the ones in node-postgres' examples, as well as cockroach's documentation.

```
const dbClient = new Client("omitted but it works")
                try {
                    await dbClient.connect()
                    await dbClient.query(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS outputs(user_id STRING NOT NULL, date_created TIMESTAMPTZ, date_modified TIMESTAMPTZ, content STRING NOT NULL, image_url STRING NOT NULL)`)
                    await dbClient.query(`INSERT INTO outputs(
                    user_id, 
                    content, 
                    image_url) 
                        VALUES(
                            $1,
                            $2,
                            $3    
                        )`,
                        [
                            userID,
                            response.results.choices[0].text,
                            response.imageResponse[0].url, 

                        ])

                } catch (e) {

                } finally {
                    dbClient.end()
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't surface the error that's being caught and ignored? It would probably explain what's going on. Maybe one of the values you're trying to insert is NULL, so you're hitting the NOT NULL constraint. Or maybe the table already exists but with a different schema, so `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` is a no-op and the insert fails because the columns it's referencing don't exist or have the wrong type.

Comment: I thought I pasted the code with it. It's a type error but it doesn't specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I just didn't understand how pg/node-postgres handles dynamic values. I had to install and use pg-format to allow me to safely use dynamic values. Here is an example:

```
 const date = new Date()
                    await dbClient.query(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS outputs(_id STRING PRIMARY KEY, user_id STRING NOT NULL, date_created TIMESTAMPTZ, date_modified TIMESTAMPTZ, content STRING NOT NULL, image_url STRING NOT NULL)`)
                    const query = format(`INSERT INTO tablename (
                    _id,
                    user_id,
                    date_created,
                    content, 
                    image_url) 
                        VALUES(
                            %L,
                            %L,
                            %L,
                            %L,
                            %L
                        )`,
                        response.id,
                        userID,
                        date.toISOString(),
                        response.choices[0].text,
                        response.url
```